# How to check whether any input word is found in a given list

Tags: c#, list, equality

```cs
public static bool isExactLocation(string item)
{
    Boolean isLocation = false;
    String[] LocationcheckList = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\list\LocationCheckList");
    List<string> LocationList = new List<string>();
    foreach (String words in LocationcheckList)
    {
        String Words = words.ToLower().Trim();
        LocationList.Add(Words);
    }
    String input = item.ToLower().Trim();
    foreach (string value in LocationList)
    {
        if (input.Equals(value))
        {
            isLocation = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isLocation;    
}
```

My location list has these values:

- Saudi
- Arabia
- Tokyo
- India
- Germany

My question when I give input as "Saudi Arabia" it should take each word in input and compare with the location list if any one the word is present in the list it should give true and that too only using equals method.

Comment: How will you handle South Korea vs South Africa?

Comment: You probably would need to split your input into parts as well and see if any of the parts is inside your LocationList - see Zahirs comment for probable problems.

Comment: `foreach (String words in LocationcheckList.SelectMany(s => s.Split())){ ... }`

Comment: Another example of why this will give false results: "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Democratic People's Republic of Korea" (i.e. North Korea), "The Gambia", "The Bahamas" (note that these are the only two examples where "the" is part of the **official name** of the country, rather than just common usage such as the Netherlands or the Philippines)

Comment: The question, to start with, is why you've chosen to separate "Saudi" and "Arabia" on two lines, as opposed to keeping them on one line and matching the full country name. This seems to be an artifact from a previous version of the code where a space-separated name list was being used - but the problem at hand has been rendered moot as your file is a **newline**-separated name list where you can easily use a space in the names themselves without conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's read the file just *once*:

```
   using System.Linq;

   ... 

   // HashSet.Contains is faster then List.Contains: O(1) vs. V(N) 
   private static HashSet<string> s_Words = new HashSet<string>(File
     .ReadLines(@"C:\list\LocationCheckList")
     .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
     .Select(item => item.Trim()), 
        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
   );
```

then you can easily check:

```
   public static bool isExactLocation(string item) {
     return item
       ?.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
       ?.All(word => s_Words.Contains(word)) ?? null;
   }
```

**Edit:** if you insist on `List<strint>` and `for` (`foreach`) loop:

```
   private static List<string> s_Words = File
     .ReadLines(@"C:\list\LocationCheckList")
     .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
     .Select(item => item.Trim())
     .ToList();
```

then we can loop...

```
   public static bool isExactLocation(string item) {
     if (null == item)
       return false;

     string[] words = item
       .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

     foreach (string word in words) {
       bool found = false;

       foreach (string location in s_Words) {
         if (location.Equals(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
           found = true;

           break;  
         } 
       }

       if (!found)
         return false;
     }   

     return true;  
  }
```

Comment: Is there any chance of adding a addition for loop in above code of mine to compare each string with list with equals method? Condition is we should not use contains method, only compare with equals method@Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: @Priya: sure, you can put nested `foreach` loops and have longer code and slower algorithm: `HashSet` implementation has `O(N)` complexity vs. `O(N^2)` in case of nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
    using System.Linq;
    LocationCheckList.Any(x=> item.Split(' ').Contains(x))
```

but watch out for "South Korea vs South Africa"

Comment: Should not use contains method tat is the condition i have so can u help me with equals method only

Comment: @Priya: The `Contains` method using in this method is not `string.Contains`, it is the  [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-5.0) method. In other words, this doesn't check if a string contains a substring. It checks if a list of strings contains a given string (exactly, i.e. using an **equality** check, not a substring find). This answer conforms to your requirement of using string equality.